# Linked In share button returns wrong URL

Tags: javascript, share, share-button

I have the flowing LinkedIn share button:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open( 'http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url='+encodeURIComponent('{{ .Permalink }}')+'&text='+encodeURIComponent('{{.Params.pageDescription}}'), 'sharer', 'width=626,height=436,top='+((screen.height - 436) / 2)+',left='+((screen.width - 626)/2 )); return false;" class="rounded-circle"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
```

Instead of sharing the page I get the "It's not you, it's us" message.

The URL is `https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle/?mini=true&url=&text=Description here`.

By comparison, this Facebook sharer **does work**:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open( 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent('{{ .Permalink }}') +'&title=' + encodeURIComponent('{{.Params.pageH1small}} - {{.Params.pageH1}}') + encodeURIComponent('{{.Params.pageDescription}}'), 'facebook-share-dialog', 'width=626,height=436,top='+((screen.height - 436) / 2)+',left='+((screen.width - 626)/2 )); return false;" class="rounded-circle"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
```

What is missing from the **LinkedIn share** button?

Comment: did you find a fix ? or a reason ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says it: **It's not you, It's us.**
This error is pretty common when there is a problem from the server's end.

It means there is no mistake from your side that is causing this error. The error happened due to some technical issues at server side from linkedIn.

So, technically you have nothing but to wait untill this issue is solved from linkedIn's end.

Answer (score 0):

It means that LinkedIn does not support the URL you created. They either can't or won't support the link that shares the article.

https://www.quora.com/What-can-be-the-reason-for-the-message-%E2%80%9CIt%E2%80%99s-not-you-It%E2%80%99s-us-Give-it-another-try-please%E2%80%9D-from-Linkedin-Does-it-mean-I%E2%80%99m-blocked-from-LinkedIn

Comment: Sorry I couldn't say. Have you been able to do this manually by constructing the URL by hand and pasting it into the address bar? Also, are you logged in properly from the session running the code?